# Exception Handling: Will parent class exception catch child exception too

Tags: java, exception, sax, saxparser, saxparseexception

[SAXException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXException.html) is extended by  [SAXNotRecognizedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXNotRecognizedException.html), [SAXNotSupportedException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/SAXNotSupportedException.html).

```
try {
  //do Something
} catch(SAXException e) {}
  catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {}
```

if lets say 'do something' has some code that throws `SAXNotRecognizedException or SAXNotSupportedException` and if that happens then nothing should happen. If SAXNotRecognizedException occurs then will nothing happen since its a empty block. Similarly for  ParserConfigurationException. Right now, even though I say do nothing for ParserConfigurationException then also a exception for ParserConfigurationException is thrown.

I basically want it to do nothing when `SAXNotRecognizedException or SAXNotSupportedException` occurs.

Comment: Well, nothing will happen anyway with this code when you catch SAXException (or a subclass).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes parent exceptions will catch child exceptions as well. A known example is when you catch **Exception**. This try block will catch all sorts(child) exceptions such as NullPointer etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to catch only `SAXNotRecognizedException` or `SAXNotSupportedException`, a better way to do it since Java 7 is:

```
try {
  // Do something
} catch(SAXNotRecognizedException | SAXNotSupportedException e) {
  // Do nothing
}
```

Note, other SAXExceptions won't be caught.